# Launch Settings->Sounds

Tags: iphone, objective-c, system-configuration

Launch Settings->Sounds

I need to launch the view of Sounds Settings in iPhone device..
Just like we get the Mail composer and Contact View using API's , can we get the Sounds Settings view?

Thanks in advance of any suggestion and help.

Comment: There isn't any sound picker in current SDK. So, one of the way - create own class with required settings.

Comment: Thanks kv0, can I change the device sound level?

Comment: Yes. See `MPVolumeView`. You can create this view and add to your huerarchy. `MPVolumeView` manipulates device's sound devices.

Comment: I want to change the device sounds level with respect to Sound Settings... i.e. if reduced the volume from my app, any incoming alert or call will ring in that level.

Comment: it's equal to change volume by buttons on device itself. [MPVolumeView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPVolumeView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: MPVolumeView sync with audio player i.e. iPod of the device...
but cannot cannot change the device sound volume.. i.e. when reduced the volume using MPVolumeView, it reflects in iPod.. But when received a call its ringing with sounds settings.. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple like to use a standard methods for certain operation.  For example changing to silent mode or adjusting the volume.  Also I wouldn't want an app changing the volume if I lowered the volume.